# Execute dynamic queries in php with pdo on a *.sql file with parameters/ variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

In my project, I use a lots of pdo queries especially prepared statement due to that my files look so bad. For clean my files I would execute sql file in who was write my prepared statement and somewhere my variables and obtain my result data.

It's for a prod Windows Server with PHP 7.2 (I have mysqli and pdo_mysql enable), Apache 2.4. I have tried to execute a sql file, it’s word fine, but idk how it’s work with prepared statement and his variables/bind and if it’s really possible in php.

```
[php]
//1 - execute a normal sql file (no prepared)

function executeSqlFile($filesql){
$req = file_get_contents($filesql);
Sql($req);
}

//2 -  my try to execute a prepared sql file

function executeSqlPreparedFile($filesql) {
  $query = file_get_contents($filesql);
  $array = explode("\n", $query);
  $b = true;
  for ($i=0; $i < count($array) ; $i++) {
    $str = $array[$i];
      if ($str != '') {
        $str .= ';';
        $b &= mysql_query($str);  
      }  
  }

return $b;
}
```

For follow code contain in query.sql:

```
SELECT 
race1.start_time, 
race1.finish_time, 
race1.penalty, 
race1.result_time, 
competitors.number, 
competitors.name, 
competitors.firstname, 
competitors.club_abrev 
    FROM race1 
        INNER JOIN competitors 
            ON race1.number = competitors.number 
WHERE  competitors.ishere = 1 
AND competitors.isfinish = 1
AND competitors.categorie_number = $categorie_number
    ORDER BY competitors.sex, 
    competitors.categorie_number, 
    race1.result_time ASC
```

I would use some thing like =>

```
execute(PATH/query.sql, array(
'categorie_number' => $categorie_key,
'bind_parameter' => $value_during_the_execution)
)
```

Comment: Why not, neat idea probably. But what's the question?

Comment: So, str_replace sounds easy. Though it looks like your code does not allow multi-line queries.

Comment: @miken32 How can I allow multi-line queries ? I known I can write this query on-line but I would use a sql.file for execute a query with bind for more ergonomics. PS: I'm so sorry for my english, is'nt my native language.